# Help identify the insects I keep finding at my house (Auburn, WA)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Could anyone tell me what is this living being is called? I keep finding his relatives flying/crawling in my house once in a while since late Summer this year. We live in Auburn, WA, in case it helps narrowing down the list of who it can be...

---

Knowing the name will help me figuring out:

- whether it's dangerous for my wife, or our infant;
- how to get rid of it (I start suspecting they either breed inside the house, or somewhere very close because I only find these insects when it's getting warmer outside).

---

Sorry for the low quality of the photo. By the way, this animal is about 15mm or 5/8" long (not measuring the legs).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a *Halyomorpha halys*, commonly known as a stink bug.  Your photo shows a brown marmorated stink bug.  More information can be found on this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_marmorated_stink_bug) page.

[image]

As far as your two questions:

- Stink bugs do not normally bite people and are not poisonous.
- A good way of controlling them in your home is by sealing any
  openings that they are entering through.

Source: http://stinkbugsguide.net/facts.htm

Comment: Wow! That was _fast_! Could you tell me how did you do that? Some kind of a book helped you, or you just 'happened to know'?

Comment: We see them all the time at our house-most commonly in autumn. I think it was my oldest child that knew what they are - I think he learned about them in school.  My children like to catch them and let them go outside.

Comment: I wish I knew a permanent solution to this problem. These buddies freak my wife out, and I'm not very comfortable with catching them... Still, many thanks, Kurt!