# What insect is this? (England)

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Found this in my room and haven't seen anything like it before. It was about 4-5cm long and has wings. Flew away before I could get a better picture. 
Photo taken from the Midlands, UK

Comment: The angle is a bit hard to see, but did it look like any of these? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41682/identification-of-an-insect-from-midwest-us https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/73638/what-type-of-insect-in-this?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/69158/help-identify-the-insects-i-keep-finding-at-my-house-auburn-wa?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It looked a bit more narrow but it's head reminded me a little bit of a stink bugs. I don't think it was that though :/ Hard to tell since it flew off!

Comment: Okay; those have only recently shown up in the UK so maybe a long shot anyways, but I think you will have trouble getting a good ID without a more clear picture unfortunately.

Comment: i think i have a answer. But it might be schocking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i have an answer it is this nice [guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_conifer_seed_bug).

[image]

Latin name is *Leptoglossus occidentalis*.

Short description of [*Leptoglossus occidentalis*](http://www.nonnativespecies.org/factsheet/factsheet.cfm?speciesId=1964):

> Western Conifer Seed Bug
>   The Western Conifer Seed Bug *Leptoglossus occidentalis* is a large and conspicuous squashbug, reaching a length of 20mm when adult. It is easily distinguished from all other GB coreids by its reddish-brown body, transverse white zigzag line across the centre of its wings and characteristic leaf-like expansions on the hind tibiae.

Comment: Still i think i am right only with genus.

Comment: It looks absolutely adorable and looks more or less like what I saw. My measurement may have been a bit off at 4-5cm.

Comment: Maybe it is some species from that genus with bigger body. Still i saw it in my home town too, so i ll try to dig more information today.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you're correct at the family level, less so further down ... the OP photo doesn't seem to show expanded hind tibiae.